# Relative homology and contractibility

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm reading Tom Dieck's "Algebraic Topology" but get stuck on proving the claim (in l.5 of p. 247):

> Claim A. If $X$ and $A$ are contractible, then $h_n(X,A)=0$.

where $h_{n}\colon\mathrm{Top}(2)\to\mathrm{Ab}$ is a homology theory satisfying

1. Homotopy invariance with respect to homotopy of $\mathrm{Top}(2)$.
2. Long exactsequence: For $(X,A)\in\mathrm{Top}(2)$, we have an exact sequence
   $$
   \cdots
   \to h_{n+1}(X,A)
   \overset{\delta}{\to} h_{n}(A, \emptyset)
   \to h_n(X,\emptyset)
   \to h_n(X,A)
   \to \cdots
   $$
   where undecorated morphisms are induced by inclusions and the connecting morphism $\delta$ is natural with respect to $(X,A)$.
3. Excision.

I can prove the following modified claim:

> Claim B. If $(X,A)$ is contractible in $\mathrm{Top}(2)$ in the sense that there is a homotopy
> $$
> F\colon (X\times I, A\times I)\to (X\times I, A\times I)
> $$
> from $\mathrm{id}_{(X,A)}$ to the constant map $(X,A)\to (X,A); x\mapsto a\in A$,
> then $h_n(X,A)=0$.

Indeed, by the homotopy invariance, we have $h_n(X,A)\cong h_n(\{a\},\{a\})$ and then the long exact sequence with $(\{a\},\{a\})\in\mathrm{Top}(2)$ gives $h_n(\{a\},\{a\})=0$.

The difference of Claim A and Claim B is whether or not the contractibility is compatible between $X$ and $A$, i.e. there is a simultaneous contraction $F\colon X\times I\to X$ of $X$ and $A$. My question is thus

> Q. Is it possible to prove Claim A without such compatibility?

If the answer is not, then I would like to know some simple counter-example preferably in the relative singular homology theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the paragraph in Dieck right before where you're having issues, note that it says that if $f \colon (X, A) \to (Y, B)$ is a map such that the components $f \colon X \to Y$ and $f \colon A \to B$ induce isomorphisms on homology, then the induced maps $f_{*} \colon h_{n}(X, A) \to h_{n}(Y, B)$ are isomorphisms.

Take $f \colon (X, A) \to (\text{pt}, \text{pt})$ to be the map of pairs whose components are the constant maps $X \to \text{pt}$, $A \to \text{pt}$. Since $X$ is contractible, it is homotopy equivalent to a point, and $f \colon X \to \text{pt}$ must be a homotopy equivalence (because there are no other maps!). Similarly, $f|_{A} \colon A \to \text{pt}$ must be a homotopy equivalence.

We know that homotopy equivalences induce isomorphisms on homology. So, putting the two paragraphs together, we have
$$h_{n}(X, A) \cong h_{n}(\{\text{pt}\}, \{\text{pt}\}) = 0.$$ Note that we don't actually have to worry about any explicit homotopies.

Comment: Thx! I understood the proof of Claim A. What I didn't notice is that it suffices to prove only $h_n(\{\mathrm{pt}\},\emptyset)\cong h_n(A,\emptyset)$ and $h_n(\{\mathrm{pt}\},\emptyset)\cong h_n(X,\emptyset)$ separately and to use the paragraph right before *without* concerning the homotopy equivalence between $(X,A)$ and $(\{\mathrm{pt}\},\{\mathrm{pt}\})$...

Comment: However, still I don't understand that $f\colon(X,A)\to (\{\mathrm{pt}\},\{\mathrm{pt}\})$ gives a homotopy equivalence in $\mathrm{Top}(2)$. What is its homotopy inverse in $\mathrm{Top}(2)$? (Although it is not needed in the proof of Claim A.)

Comment: It's not true that both spaces $X,A$ being contractible implies that $(X,A)\simeq(\ast,\ast)$ in $Top(2)$. A counterexample is given in Problem 3 on pg. 33.

Comment: @opus26 Oops, Tyrone is right and I am wrong; you don't necessarily have a homotopy equivalence of pairs. But as you note in your comment, this is not an issue.

Comment: @Tyrone Thx! In the first post, I couldn't extract that another question by myself but it has been also answered!

Comment: @ckefa Thx for your comment. I would appreciate if you correct the answer in case you have time.

Comment: @Tyrone You are correct, I have removed the incorrect statements.